# How to redirect path to the URL with parameters?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, redirect, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an endpoint which supports paging: `api/accounts?pageNumber=1&pageSize=50`

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetAccounts(int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        var accounts = _accountService.GetAccounts(pageNumber, pageSize);

        Response.Headers.Add("X-Pagination", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(accounts.GetMetadata()));

        return Ok(accounts);
    }
```

But if someone sends, technically `bad request` with pageSize too big or without paging parameters at all, instead of sending back `400 status` I would like to redirect it to the proper URL with defaults parameters. Which means:

If someone types `api/accounts` in the browser, he will be redirected to `api/accounts?pageNumber=1&pageSize=50`. I want him to see a new URL in his browser. Also if someone do this:

`api/accounts?pageNumber=1&pageSize=500000000`, I want to do exactly the same as in the previous example, go to this:  `api/accounts?pageNumber=1&pageSize=50` and show it in the browser.

Can you please help me out with this?
Thanks

Comment: Make both parameters nullable (optional). Then within the method check if they have a value. No, assign defaults. Yes, check their values and if outside allowed values, assign default(s).

Comment: @CodingYoshi This is how I'm doing it now actually. But when  I type `api/accounts` in the browser, I'm getting page1 with 50pcs indeed, but the address bar still says `api/accounts`. I want the address bar to be change so it reflects what's actually in the response

Comment: For that you would need to do a 301 redirect. You can just redirect to the same method.

Answer (score 0):

> If someone types api/accounts in the browser, he will be redirected to api/accounts?pageNumber=1&pageSize=50. I want him to see a new URL in his browser.
>
> Also if someone do this: api/accounts?pageNumber=1&pageSize=500000000, I want to do exactly the same as in the previous example, go to this: api/accounts?pageNumber=1&pageSize=50 and show it in the browser.

To achieve above requirement, you can refer to the following example using a [URL redirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

*In Startup.cs*

```
using (StreamReader iisUrlRewriteStreamReader =
    File.OpenText("IISUrlRewrite.xml"))
{
    var options = new RewriteOptions()
        .AddIISUrlRewrite(iisUrlRewriteStreamReader);

    app.UseRewriter(options);
}
```

*IISUrlRewrite.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="urrl1" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="api/accounts" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
            <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="pageNumber=([0-9]{1,3})&amp;pageSize=(10|50|100)$" negate="true" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="api/accounts?pageNumber=1&amp;pageSize=50" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

*Test Result*

[image]